# React native KeyboardAvoidingView not moving correctly

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a `TextInput` that when pressed gets covered by the keyboard. So I wrapped it in a `KeyboardAvoidingView`. But regardless of the behavior that I set for this view, the `TextInput` won't move above the keyboard. Using `position` as the behavior moves the `TextInput` but only half way above the keyboard, while the other two don't seem to work at all.

I also tried wrapping my entire component with a `KeyboardAvoidingView`, but doing so breaks the entire layout.

Can anyone help me? I never managed to get `KeyboardAvoidingView` to work for me and now I really need it. Thanks in advance!

Here is my component. Also worth mentioning is that this component is top level(well, almost top level since it's wrapped in a Router)

```
const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('screen')

const style = StyleSheet.create({
    main: {
        height,
        width,
        flexDirection: 'column',
    },
    iconSelecter: {
        width,
        height: 196,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: Colors.primary,
        marginTop: 32
    },
    icon: {
        height: 164,
        width: 164,
    },
    saveButton: {
        width: 96,
        height: 96,
        borderRadius: 100,
        backgroundColor: Colors.secondary,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignSelf: 'center',
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: 96 + 32
    },
    saveIcon: {
        height: 54,
        width: 54,
    },
    textInputWrapper: {
        borderBottomColor: Colors.textInputBorder,
        width: 288,
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        marginTop: 96,
        height: 48,
    },
    textInput: {
        fontWeight: "300",
        fontSize: 14,
        margin: 0
    },
    hintWrapper: {
        alignSelf: 'center',
        marginTop: 4
    },
    hint: {
        fontSize: 12,
        fontFamily: "Roboto-Thin",
        fontStyle: 'normal',
    }
})


    const CreateActivity = ({ goBack }: NavigationProps) => {

    //////////////////////////////
    //State and logic 
    ///////////////


        return (
            // TODO: Add touchable opacity to dismiss keyboard

            <View style={style.main}>
                <Appbar title="New activity" canGoBack goBack={goBack} />
                <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                    <View style={style.iconSelecter}>
                        <GestureRecognizer onSwipeLeft={nextIcon} onSwipeRight={lastIcon}>
                            <Image style={style.icon} source={icons[currentIconIndex]?.file}></Image>
                        </GestureRecognizer>
                    </View>
                    <View style={style.hintWrapper}>
                        <Text style={style.hint}>Swipe to cycle through the icons</Text>
                    </View>

                    <KeyboardAvoidingView>
                        <View style={style.textInputWrapper}>
                            <TextInput style={style.textInput} placeholder={"Give this activity a name"} value={name} onChangeText={setName}></TextInput>
                        </View>
                    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
                    <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={createActivity} background={TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple("#fff", true)}>
                        <View style={style.saveButton}>
                            <Image style={style.saveIcon} source={require("../../assets/icons/light/save.png")}></Image>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableNativeFeedback>
                </View>
            </View>

        )
    }


    export default CreateActivity;
```

Comment: Did you try adding a scrollview to the container view?

Comment: Isn't it supposed to work without a scrollview?

Comment: scrollview will help the textbox move above keyboard when selected

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest that you to try wrap all the content of the screen in `<KeyboardAvoidingView />` (or make it one of the outermost elements), otherwise it only will slide up its children (the View and the TextInput) leaving the rest of the content in its original position, making the layout look overlaped and weird. If you do that, the value "position" should work fine.

Something like this:

```js
<View style={style.main}>
    <Appbar title="New activity" canGoBack goBack={goBack} />
    <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="position" >
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}> // --> Remove flex: 1 if you experience some issue with the positioning
          <View style={style.iconSelecter}>
              <GestureRecognizer onSwipeLeft={nextIcon} onSwipeRight={lastIcon}>
                  <Image style={style.icon} source={icons[currentIconIndex]?.file}></Image>
              </GestureRecognizer>
          </View>
          <View style={style.hintWrapper}>
              <Text style={style.hint}>Swipe to cycle through the icons</Text>
          </View>

          <KeyboardAvoidingView>
              <View style={style.textInputWrapper}>
                  <TextInput style={style.textInput} placeholder={"Give this activity a name"} value={name} onChangeText={setName}></TextInput>
              </View>
          </KeyboardAvoidingView>
          <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={createActivity} background={TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple("#fff", true)}>
              <View style={style.saveButton}>
                  <Image style={style.saveIcon} source={require("../../assets/icons/light/save.png")}></Image>
              </View>
          </TouchableNativeFeedback>
      </View>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
</View>
```

Also see the comment in the code above. Check if you really need to use of flex: 1 in all the outer wrapper elements, and take a look to the `height` you are setting in the `style.main` based on dimentions. I don't think that it is necesary and I think it could lead to some measure issues if you fix the height of the parent container.

EDIT:

I was just digging in react-native docs and I realize that there is a zIndex that you could use to avoid ablsolute positioning. It is a relative style prop so it needs to be set between sibling views, like this:

```js
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <View style={[styles.appbarShape, styles.appbarZIndex]} ><Text>Header</Text></View>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="position" style={styles.contentZIndex}>
          {other children}
          <TextInput placeholder="enter text"/>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  appbarShape: {
    height: 80,
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignSelf: "stretch",
    backgroundColor: "#FFF"
  },
  appbarZIndex: {
    zIndex: 3,
  },
  contentZIndex: {
    zIndex: 0
  }
});
```

Since the view that represents the appbar has a greater zIndex it shows up over the ones with a lower zIndex
Check this out working in this snack https://snack.expo.io/5VXAcw4Y0

Docs: https://reactnative.dev/docs/layout-props

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yeah, now the input gets moved above the keyboard, but I have the same issue as with using KeyboardAwareScrollView. Even though the Appbar isn't wrapped inside KeyboardAwareView, it gets pusshed off-scren when keyboard appears. Shouldn't only the childs of this view get moved around when the keyboard appears?

Comment: Yes, it should. I haven't used Appbar (I assume you're using this component https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/appbar.html), but I was thinking... Is int possible the content moved upwards is covering the Appbar component instead of pushing it out of the screen? Could you check that?

Comment: Also if the appbar component is a custom component writen by yourself, check this snack out https://snack.expo.io/p_silSnca It demonstrates the that KeyboardAvoidingView works properly even without a scrollView, but you need to set the absolute positioning to the appbar view. (click the android or ios tab on the emulator, otherwise the keyboard won't appear if you're in web mode)

Comment: I am going to check right now. It's a custom compent, but I let it in the flex layout without abolute position

Comment: So, I tried replicating your example, even though it messed my UI, but just to try see if it worked. I also changed `windowSoftInputMode` in AndroidManafest.xml. So... in adjustPan (what I had so far), when the keyboard appears, all the content gets moved, despite the behavior. Adjusting margins around, the actual content is going below the Appbar, and when the keyboard appears I could see the appbar actually getting pushed off-screen. In adjustResize mode, KeyboardAvoidingView doesn't do anything. Even with no heigths set anywhere, it doesn't move anything when the keyboard appears

Comment: I just added another option you can use to my initial answer, I tried it and it works. Sadly I can't see the problem in your code, it should be ok.

Comment: I was already using zIndex for the Appbar, but with or without, the  behavior stays the same

Comment: I fixed it. I changed the windowSoftInputMode to adjustResize, set KeyboardAvoidngView behavior to hight and added flex 1 to both the top view and the KeyboardAvoidingView.Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 4):

Use `react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view`

```
<KeyboardAwareScrollView extraHeight={135} enabledOnAndroid={true} 
extraScrollHeight={70} style={styles.mainContainer}
automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={true}
enableOnAndroid={true}
keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'
scrollEnabled={true} >

//your form 

</KeyboardAwareScrollView>



 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    mainContainer: { flex: 1, marginHorizontal: 15, marginVertical: 15 },
});
```

Comment: Ok, this works. But I wanted to keep my AppBar visible so I wrapped only the actual content in a KeyboardAwareScrollView. But when I press the TextInput, the AppBar goes off-screen. If I try to scroll to the top, the scroll stops exactly before the AppBar. Is this the normal behavior  that when the keyboard is active, only the KeyboardAwareScrollView is on the screen, or can it be overridden?

Comment: Also, because I didn't include the styling of the AppBar. It is places in the normal flex layout, no absolute position at the top